# NoReverseMatch at /new_application/check_login/

Tags: django

I am new to DJango. I am getting error 'NoReverseMatch at /new_application/check_login/' while redirecting view from another view.
different files listed below.

Main **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^new_application/', include('new_application.urls')),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Login

...

def check_login(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_application:loggedin',args=(user,)))


def loggedin(request, user):
    return render(request, 'new_application/loggedin.html',{'full_name': user.first_name +" "+ user.last_name})
```

Application **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'new_application'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^check_login/$', views.check_login, name='check_login'),
    url(r'^loggedin/$', views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),
    url(r'^invalid_login/$', views.invalid_login, name='invalid_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Here is an error image : [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssVgy.jpg)

please give the solution for fixing this error.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern must match against the given url...

```
url(r'^loggedin/(?P<user>\w+)/$', views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse should match one of URL names from urls.py

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loggedin',args=(user,)))
```